# Calculate percentage for measure in Power BI

Tags: powerbi

I have table with  2 columns with columns named as "Month_P" and "Total"

Month_P                   Total

Jan                        511

Feb                        601

Mar                        800

April                       900

May                        1000

I would like to calculate the percentage of sale on current month with next month to get the percentage of the sale for current month for example Jan =511 and Feb = 601 then it would be (601-511)/511. how can i write the measure in power BI to apply all the rows

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a date column? (or Calendar Table connected to this table based on some key). If not then you should change your model. With a string data column we cant do much.

for example if i have in Calendar [MonthKey] as {year+month}: 202001, 202002, 202003:

```
Measure%% = 

var __curDate = calculate(sum(Table[SomeValue]))
var __prevDate = calculate(sum(Table[SomeValue]), filter(ALL(Calendar), Calendar[MonthKey] - 1 = selectedvalue(Calendar[MonthKey]) ))
return DIVIDE( (__curDate- __prevDate), _curDate )
```

Comment: Thank you for your help

Comment: I added the measure named as msta42a and column Monthkey to Total_withFilters table. I have filters on the dashboard for Gender,Language and Sale Type. it works but when i select the filter on the dashboard it does not calculate correctly according to the filter

Comment: msta42a = var _curDate = CALCULATE(sum(Total_withFilters[total])) 
var _preDate =CALCULATE(sum(Total_withFilters[total]),FILTER(ALL(Total_withFilters),Total_withFilters[MonthKey]-1 = SELECTEDVALUE(Total_withFilters[MonthKey]) )) 
 return DIVIDE( (_curDate - _preDate), _curDate)

Comment: Please help me to apply the filter from the dashboard to measure. I am new to power BI. and i could not find any solutions.  Thanks again

Comment: Edit your main question and add some dummy data and desired output + info about filters;